Issue of subscription to one topic of Firebase Cloud Messaging in iOS app by using KastriFree library and Delphi 11
I am writing a small test app for IOS by using delphi 11 and Kastri Free library, the test was ok on my ipad.
I can receive notifications from Firebase cloud messaging.
But when I tried to subscribe one topic to FCM from ipad, I got an error message.
I use the method subscribeToTopic from DW.iOSapi.Firebase as follow, but got “access violation” by taping a button on my ipad.
var _FMessaging: FIRMessaging;

begin

_FMessaging.subscribeToTopic(StrtoNSstr(‘test’)) ;

end;

Can anyone point out the possible cause?
